# Is there an R package that computes homoplasy excess ratios (HER)?

Tags: r, phylogenetics, phylogeny, covid-19, sars-cov-2

I want to calculate the homoplasy excess ratio for a phylogenetic tree, for example homoplasy resulting from recombination.

I am wondering if there are any R packages out there that will do this?

I have looked at phyloseq, Rphylopars, phylocurve, PhylogeneticEM, PhyloinformR, but these packages do not have functions that calculate HER. I searched "homoplasy excess ratio" on bioconductor, but it returned ca. 3000 packages.

Answer (score 1):

Maynard's Smith's homoplasy is what you want and it is available in the recombination detection package (RDP) described [here](https://academic.oup.com/ve/article/1/1/vev003/2568683). Its really a Windows package rather than R.